# How to boot the ubuntu cloud image with a customized kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, qemu

I try to use **my own Linux kernel built from source** for an [ubuntu cloud image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/release/) and boot it using QEMU. My customized kernel is outside of the ubuntu image:

```
$ ls
kernel   ubuntu-20.04-amd64.img  ...
```

Here is the command line I used:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2 -m 4096 -nographic \
    -drive id=root,media=disk,file=ubuntu-20.04-amd64.img \
    -kernel ./kernel/arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0" \
    -device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:5555-:22
```

When I boot it, I can see the following log:

```
[    0.875446] List of all partitions:
[    0.875736] 0800         4194304 sda 
[    0.875736]  driver: sd
[    0.876259]   0801         4194303 sda1 00000000-01
[    0.876259] 
[    0.876893] No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
[    0.876893]  ext3
[    0.877435]  ext2
[    0.877610]  ext4
[    0.877834] 
[    0.878149] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it boot without the kernel option?

Comment: Yes, it boots w/o the -kernel option @wxz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log you quote says that the disk image is partitioned: that is, sda is the entire (virtual) disk, and it has a partition table with one partition named sda1. Your "append" command line asks to use '/dev/sda' as if the disk image had only a single filesystem on it. Try '/dev/sda1' instead.